# Why can't I see how long ago someone was on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I used to be able to see how long time ago someone was on Facebook. She uses the desktop website, not a smartphone app. For the last couple of weeks I can't see that. Do you know why? She didn't unfriend me. I can send her messages and find her in a search bar, so I don't think she blocked me. But why I can't see when she is on Facebook or how long ago she was on Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Probably she has changed her FB password and choose to logoff from all devices.

By doing this anyone can hide last login time. Make sure you have not logged-in on phone with FB or messenger.